# For react-navigation + web, directly navigating to a nested route via URL results in missing back button in the header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have HomeScreen with a link that goes to DeckScreen. When I click a button to navigate to the DeckScreen, the back button in the header bar shows up fine.

[image: Shows Up Fine]

But when I reload the page in browser or directly navigate to this URL (localhost/deck), there is no back button.

[image]

And clicking on the BottomTab doesn't do anything, will not take us back Home.

[image]

I am using BottomTab that has a HomeStack, which contains the HomeScreen and DeckScreen.

```
export default function Navigation () {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} theme={DefaultTheme}>
      <RootNavigator/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

function RootNavigator () {

  return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name='Root' component={Nav} options={{headerShown: false, ...fade}}/>
  <Stack.Group screenOptions={{presentation: 'modal'}}>
    <Stack.Screen name='Modal' component={ModalScreen}/>
  </Stack.Group>
</Stack.Navigator>
  ）；
}


function HomeStackScreen () {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName='dashboard'>
      <HomeStack.Screen name='dashboard' component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown: false, title: 'Dashboard'}}/>
      <HomeStack.Screen name='deck' component={DeckScreen} options={{title: 'Deck'}}/>
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function Nav ({navigation}) {    
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName='home'
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
     }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name='home'
        component={HomeStackScreen}
       })}
     />
  
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

And here is my Linking:

```
const linking: LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
 prefixes: [Linking.makeUrl('/')],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Root: {
        screens: {
          home: {
            screens: {
              dashboard: 'dashboard',
              deck: 'deck' 
            },
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I've tried using `getStateFromPath` to try to inject a route in stack but it doesn't work and feels wrong.

How do you tell React Navigation, this screen is part of a stack, and it should always have a back button in that header?

Comment: in your `linking`, I found a screen named `Root`, but I don't see it in any of the `navigator`

Comment: I edited to add the full code. Sorry, I excluded some code to point to relevant parts.

Comment: well, I had the same issue with history and go back and gave up . it doesn't know which screen to go to even you set the back behavior​ . I did use the screen option to manually set the back URL for each screen , it works better when you have nested stacks and you have better control

Comment: @ngokevin, sorry i'll continue checking after finishing some of my tasks

Comment: what is `HomeStack`? is it a `BottomTab`? can you share the code or explain more about that? I already post an answer below about one of your questions, but need more explanation for the `BottomTab` problem

Comment: Thanks, it's `const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why there's no back button when you're opening from the link is most likely because you don't set `headerLeft` in the screen and there's no other screen in the navigation stack (you went directly to the `DeckScreen`).

You can set the back button in the `option` in `Screen`, like this example below:

```js
function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
              title="Info"
              color="#fff"
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

You can find the example [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/)

Comment: Thanks! I will do this workaround and manually specify back buttons for every screen. Also this seems to be a big flaw in react-navigation with Web? If there's a config where you can specify all linking, and you navigate to a nested screen, react-navigation should automatically populate the bottom of the stack based on the path?

Comment: I am marking this as the Answer, as a workaround: Specify `headerLeft`, passing in a Back icon with a manual onPress for every nested screen. I'd love still to see if potentially react-navigation can handle this on its own if it's passed a linking config。

Comment: @ngokevin no problem! yea, I'm not sure if they have that kind of configuration.

Comment: :) They do have Linking config that should work. But I get that Web isn't a first-class citizen

Comment: @ngokevin, btw try adding `initialRouteName` to the Linking config next to screens, that will probably let you go back to the `initialRoute` from the screen that you open from the link. You still need the `headerButton` that calls `navigation.goBack()` tho.